# Dwarven Ale curse Munchkin

Tags: munchkin

We have a dwarf player who got Dwarven Ale as curse that gives him +4 on battle (only for Dwarfs). But he got temporary amnesia on the next turn. And he forget that he is a Dwarf.
Our question is: will Ale give him +4 on this turn or not ?

We have a heated debate around this question. Does amnesia eliminates Ale effect ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not in the FAQ. But the Temporary Amnesia is mentioned on [a forum](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=76986).

**Question:**

> Had a little debate in a game today over this one...
>
> I say that since the card (Temporary Amnesia) says you are Human "for all purposes", that trumps items like Casting Couch for special powers and Fake Ears and
> Fake Beard for the sake of monster bonus/penalty and Race/Class
> specific items.
>
> The other side says that those are simply items that override or
> sidestep your actual Races/Classes and are thus not affected by
> Temporary Amnesia. You're actually a plain old Human, but if you put
> on Fake Ears, monsters will think you're an Elf, and so on.
>
> Which is right?

**Answer**

> Your friends are right. Fake Ears/Beard don't actually change your Race; they just change the way it appears. The fact that you don't remember your real Race doesn't affect how those Items work.

This implies that as long as Temporary Amnesia is in effect, you are not a dwarf so the +4 does not apply. But if you wear a fake beard, the +4 again works.